# Does CMake support glibc feature test macros

Tags: linux, cmake, posix, glibc, portability

Let's say I want to use a specific Linux / POSIX feature, that is provided conditionally based on [feature test macros](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Feature-Test-Macros.html). For example, the type `cpu_set_t`, the macro `CPU_SET_ZERO`, and the function `sched_setaffinity`.

Ideally I would just like to tell CMake that I need those, and it should figure out what extra feature test macros to set or fail with a nice error message if it can't be provided on the current system. Is that possible?

I am aware that I can lookup in [the](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_setaffinity.2.html) [manpages](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/CPU_SET.3.html) and manually use [`add_definitions(-D_GNU_SOURCE)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_definitions.html), but that can become tedious once multiple functionalities that were introduced and deprecated in different versions of the POSIX standard are combined. In my experience, it can become difficult to maintain portability across different versions of the glibc implementation.

There are the [CMake platform checks](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:How_To_Write_Platform_Checks), but they only seem to help in checking. So I get the error during `cmake` rather than `make`, but I still have to figure out the right feature test macros manually.

[cmake-compile-features](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-compile-features.7.html) seem to offer only features directly related to the compiler, not the library.

Answer (score 3):

If you are just looking to determine whether a function or variable exists, you can use the [`CheckSymbolExists`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/module/CheckSymbolExists.html) module. Likewise, there is [`CheckStructHasMember`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/module/CheckStructHasMember.html) for structs (assuming there is a standard member you can check for). So:

```
include (CheckSymbolExists)
include (CheckStructHasMember)

CHECK_SYMBOL_EXISTS(CPU_SET_ZERO sched.h CPU_SET_ZERO_exists)
CHECK_SYMBOL_EXISTS(sched_setaffinity sched.h sched_setaffinity_exists)
CHECK_STRUCT_HAS_MEMBER(cpu_set_t <member?> sched.h cpu_set_t_exists)
```

It appears that `cpu_set_t` is an opaque type, so instead you can use the [`CheckCXXSourceCompiles`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/module/CheckCXXSourceCompiles.html) module, which is a frontend for the [`try_compile`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/command/try_compile.html) command. It is a generic way to determine if any particular code compiles. `try_compile` is used extensively by 'base' CMake to determine features (try a search in the Modules directory!). Essentially, you pass it in a minimal source file, which should fail compilation if your feature is not present, and it reports back to your CMake script the result.